# All instances of a class share the same values

Tags: c++, class

I've got a class called Data, whenever I declare a new instance of this class and change something in it, it changes all instances of that class. I'm not sure how to fix this, or why it is even happening.

(Note, I've stripped back a lot of what was in my data class, but this example still produces the error)

Data.h

```
#include <chrono>

volatile class Data{
    public:
        volatile struct Ts{
            volatile int64_t unixTimestamp;
        };

        int ReturnTimestamp() volatile;
        void SetTimestamp(int) volatile;
};
```

Data.cpp

```
#include "data.h"
#include <ctime>

volatile Data::Ts data;


int Data::ReturnTimestamp() volatile{
    return data.unixTimestamp;
}

void Data::SetTimestamp(int timestamp) volatile{
    data.unixTimestamp = timestamp;
}
```

In main I run

```
int main() {
    Data d1;
    Data d2;
    Data d3;

    d1.SetTimestamp(1);
    d2.SetTimestamp(2);
    d3.SetTimestamp(3);

    printf("%i %i %i\n", d1.ReturnTimestamp(), d2.ReturnTimestamp(), d3.ReturnTimestamp());

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

> 3 3 3

I want the output to be

> 1 2 3

Why is it not "1 2 3" ?

Comment: The classes are empty, have no member variables. You change the global variable.

Comment: @273K is data (in data.cpp) not a member variable?

Comment: No it's not. Just because it is defined in the class's `cpp` file doesn't make it a member variable. C++ does not work this way. It must be declared as a class member, in the class declaration. Which specific C++ textbook are you using, this should be explained there?

Comment: You are using `volatile`.  Do you **know** why you are using `volatile`?

Comment: Pretty sure that volatile should be atomic instead.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow Why?  There are no threads in the OP's code (so far as we know).

Comment: @PaulSanders Because I don't think the unixTimestamp is refering to some hardware registers that changes on it's own and thus must be volatile. (The more modern way would be to do volatile read and write instead of declaring the variable volatile.) If threads are involved then atomic is the way to go. The volatile keyword could also simply be wrong an nothing is needed at all, like in the shown code. But if the volatile was there for a reason I still think it atomic would probably the right answer.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow  _if the volatile was there for a reason_ trust me, it wasn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

data is not defined in the class, so you create a global variable. Create a member variable.

```cpp
class Data{
    public:
        struct Ts{
            volatile int64_t unixTimestamp;
        } data;

        int ReturnTimestamp() volatile;
        void SetTimestamp(int) volatile;
};
```

instead of `volatile Data::Ts data;`